Python Tkinter universal “Back” button
I currently have a GUI with a “Return Home” button, which is three lines:
def “funcX”(self):
    self.pagey.pack_forget()
    self.home.pack()

Which will “forget” Page Y and re-create Home.
But I don’t think I need to write this for every page in my program. Is there an elegant way to write:
self.”current”.pack_forget 

Which will forget whatever frame is current and open the Home frame?
Searched the Tkinter literature and adjacent or relevant stackoverflow threads…all seem more focused on “destroying” windows or frames…

It depends on your current design, so it is better to provide a [mre].

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
